# PaperJS zoom and pan

Tags: javascript, canvas, zooming, paperjs, pan

I have successfully implemented a zooming feature based on [this example](https://matthiasberth.com/tech/stable-zoom-and-pan-in-paperjs)

```
 zoom: function(delta, point){
    if (!delta) return;

    var
        oldZoom = paper.view.zoom,
        oldCenter = paper.view.center,
        viewPos = paper.view.viewToProject(point);
        newZoom = delta > 0 ? oldZoom * 1.05 : oldZoom / 1.05;

    if (!this.allowedZoom(newZoom)) return;

    var
        zoomScale = oldZoom / newZoom,
        centerAdjust = viewPos.subtract(oldCenter),
        offset = viewPos.subtract(centerAdjust.multiply(zoomScale)).subtract(oldCenter);

    paper.view.center = view.center.add(offset);
},

allowedZoom: function(zoom){
    zoom = Math.max(zoom, this.settings.minZoom);
    zoom = Math.min(zoom, this.settings.maxZoom);

    if (zoom !== paper.view.zoom)
    {
        paper.view.zoom = zoom;
        return zoom;
    }
    return null;
}
```

however this does not take into account the position of the view when you zoom out back to the original `scale = 1`. What I mean is I would like the view to stick to the canvas edge.

Here's a screenshot[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the answer if anyone else stumbles upon this. The key is simply to check the bounds of the view then adjust accordingly:

```
    bounds = paper.view.bounds;

    if (bounds.x < 0) paper.view.center = paper.view.center.subtract(new Point(bounds.x, 0));
    if (bounds.y < 0) paper.view.center = paper.view.center.subtract(new Point(0, bounds.y));

    bounds = paper.view.bounds;
    var 
        w = bounds.x + bounds.width,
        h = bounds.y + bounds.height;

    if (w > paper.view.viewSize.width) paper.view.center = paper.view.center.subtract(new Point(w - paper.view.viewSize.width, 0));
    if (h > paper.view.viewSize.height) paper.view.center = paper.view.center.subtract(new Point(0, h - paper.view.viewSize.height));
```

Comment: why did you twice, assign a value to bounds?